# Launch a batch file stored in different directory from Python script in another directory

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, call, popen

I have created a Python script which needs to launch a **.bat** file based on some condition.

Python script location : **\Component\myScript.py**

Batch file location : **\Component\MS20160825\toExecute.bat**
*The batch file internally uses some executables which are in* **\Component\bin\**

How do I do following :

1. Launch .BAT file from Python script so that .BAT executes successfully. BAT file should be able to find executables in **\Component\bin\** directory to perform its task and produces desired result.
2. Hold Python script execution until .BAT finished its execution.
3. .BAT file has **pause >nul** statement. I need to bypass it, meaning when .BAT is executed from Python script it should not wait for user to press **Enter** rather it should terminate normally after executing second last statement. Because the same .BAT file needs to be executed multiple times.

Comment: Run the batch file from Python script with a parameter like `NoPause` and use in the batch file `if /I not "%~1" == "NoPause" pause >nul`. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` to get help on how to make use of batch file parameters. `%0` references argument 0 which is the batch file itself. `%~dp0` is for example drive and path to batch file ending with a backslash. That might be useful to reference other folders/files from within batch file with a path relative to path of batch file.

Comment: About relative paths: A path starting with a backslash like `\Component\myScript.py` is relative to __root of current drive__. A path starting with ``..\`` references the parent directory of current directory. And a path starting with ``.\`` or with a folder or file name is relative to current directory.

Comment: Yes that was a typing mistake. Thanks Mofi for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Should solve all problems you are experiencing!

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('batch.bat', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked but requires a small correction.
i.e.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all for their active suggestion.
With small correction following code worked for me:

```
import subprocess

batchFileLocation = 'Component\\MS20160825'
batchFileFullPath = os.path.join(batchFileLocation, 'toExecute.bat')

p = subprocess.Popen(os.path.abspath(batchFileFullPath), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, cwd = batchFileLocation)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
```

Here **cwd** argument is very much important, it needs to be updated with the location where batch file is placed then only the batch file will be able to execute correctly.

After that only batch file will be able to search for the binary (placed in a different directory like **Component\bin\** in this case) required for its execution.